# hiding or showing a section of the view based on value in a table column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, ruby-on-rails-4

I feel like this is pretty simple, but apparently I can't find the answer on SO.

I have a model called `Events` and a column called `status`. I want to show a badge on my view called *pending*, only when the value of `event.status = pending`.

I've tried this:

```
<% if event.status.pending? %>
  <span class="badge badge-warning">pending</span>
<% end %>
```

But when I do this the error says:

```
   undefined method `pending?' for "unscheduled":String
```

*unscheduled* and *scheduled* are the other values the column could have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
<%  if event.status == 'pending' %>
```

To additionally check for its `presence`:

```
<% if event.status.present? && event.status == 'pending' %>
```

On top of that you can add a function to your `Event` model to make `.pending?` work:

**events.rb**

```
def self.pending?
  true if self.status == "pending"
end
```

And then you can simply call that from your **view**

```
<% if event.pending? %>
```

Comment: Yes!  Thank you.  Will accept as soon as it lets me.

Comment: How would I convey 'is not NIL'?